# unable to save PHP objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Getting 'zero-length keys are not allowed' FATAL error while saving object.

Is it due to presence of __construct() ?

I believe PHP object is allowed in save() method.

```
class Address{
    private $name;
    private $company;
    private $zip;

    public function __construct($name,$company,$zip){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->company = $company;
        $this->zip = $zip;
    }
}

$newAddress = new Address("james","google",678);

print_r($newAddress);
// Address Object ( [name:Address:private] => james [company:Address:private] =>
// google [zip:Address:private] => 678 )

$addresses->save($newAddress);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?' in /var/www/html/index.php:105 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php(105): MongoCollection->save(Object(Address)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 105

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Umm, how do you expect mongo to read your *private* class variables.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, after making public, i am able to save successfully.